# PEM Modules Redundancy in Juniper SRX3600 series Firewall

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-srx, power

We have Juniper SRX3600 running in our network. At the moment only 2 x PEM Modules (AC Power Supply) are installed in the chassis while other 2 x PEM are not. This is shown below from the output of 'show chassis environment'.

```
user@SRX3600> show chassis environment 
Class Item                           Status     Measurement
Temp  PEM 0                          OK         24 degrees C / 75 degrees F
      PEM 1                          OK         24 degrees C / 75 degrees F
      PEM 2                          Absent    
      PEM 3                          Absent
```

However when 1 x PEM Module goes down due to issue in input power supply , then all line cards (FPC / SPC) are down except Routine Engine (observed by the output of 'show chassis routing-engine').

It is clear that both PEM 0 and PEM 1 are required for normal working of SRX3600. If we want to introduce PEM 2 and PEM 3 into the chassis , then how will be the redundancy work i.e. which PEM modules will be backup of each other when there are 4 x PEMs installed?

We do have multiple input sources of power supplies in the data supplies. Hence is it possible to provide input power to 2 x PEMs (which are backup of each other , I dont know which PEMs) from one source and remaining 2 x PEMs getting power from the other source?

*In this way , there will be redundancy not only from PEMs perspective but also from input power supply source.*

**Just for information**

This level of redundancy is currently working for Juniper MX960s in data center which have 4 x PEMs installed with 2 x PEMs getting power from one source while other 2 x PEMs getting power from other source.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need one or two more PEMs.  This Juniper [document](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/release-independent/junos/topics/reference/specifications/services-gateway-srx3600-ac-power-requirements.html) is a good planning resource for SRX3600 power budgeting.

All the PEMs in the SRX3600 load-share so the problem isn't which slots are occupied by PEMs but rather the total available power supply.  There are no *zones* or similar complications like there are in some other Juniper chassis.